# How to change groupId picture in maven repository

Tags: maven, deployment, artifacts

Is there any way how to change default picture on my maven artifacts next to groupId ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the [site descriptor](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/sitedescriptor.html) you can define images etc. which you like to display.

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <bannerLeft>
    <name>Project Name</name>
    <src>http://maven.apache.org/images/apache-maven-project-2.png</src>
    <href>http://maven.apache.org/</href>
  </bannerLeft>

  <bannerRight>
    <src>http://maven.apache.org/images/maven-logo-2.gif</src>
  </bannerRight>
  ...
</project>
```

If you want more flexibility to change the format of the pages you can define [your own skin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creatingskins.html).

Comment: what if it's in Gradle?